# its showing its id in the update.php file ,query runs succesfully but not updating the product image,name and description?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

products are not updating ,while the query runs successfully in php

in my datatable.php file

```
<td style="padding:50px;"><a href="update.php?call=<?php echo

$fetch1['pro_id'];?>" class="btn btn-light">update</a></td>
```

in my update.php file

```
<?php
include "config.php";

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {

    $user_id = $_GET['call'];

    $proname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['proname']);
    $des = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['des']);

    $folder = "upload2/";

    $name = $_FILES['image1']['name'];

    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    $path1 = $folder . $name;

    if ($_FILES["image1"]["size"] >= 2097152) {
        echo "<br>Sorry, your file must be less or equal than 2mb ";
    }

    if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif") {

        echo "<br>Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG,,GIF files are allowed.";

    } else {

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'], $path1);

        $query = "update products set proname='$proname',des='$des',img='$path1' where pro_id='$user_id'";

        $run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        header('location:datatable.php');
    }
}

?>
```

if i put "$user_id=$_GET['call'];" before isset then show undefine index
and if i put it after isset then query runs but show no updation

Comment: How have you confirmed that the query runs successfully?  You never examine the query, examine the result, or check for errors.

Comment: Turn on error reporting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5438060/296555 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/14578243/296555.

Comment: `<a href="update.php...` will generate a GET request. How can it go into `if (isset($_POST['reg_user']))`?

Comment: i have already changer it to get but nothing happens

Comment: @AhmadBilal: Define "nothing happens".  You're not doing any debugging.  Even if you change that `if` statement to use the GET array that value still won't be in that array.  (Because you're not passing that value to the server in that link.)  So the query never executes.  Stop *assuming* that the query is successfully executing and start *debugging*.

Comment: : Undefined index: call in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\update.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: proname in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\update.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: des in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\update.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: image1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\update.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: image1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\update.php on line 28

Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG,,GIF files are allowed.

its showing me that errors if i use $_GET

Comment: kindly correct the code of what you are telling me i will be very thankful to you or  modify it

Comment: @AhmadBilal: Using GET doesn't seem like the correct approach here.  Take a step back.  What specifically do you want to *do* in this code?  It looks like you're trying to post a form with a file.  But in the HTML all you have is a link.  A link is not a form.  If you want to post a form then create your form in HTML.

Comment: the link is in the form bro

Comment: @AhmadBilal: (1) The code in the question shows no form.  (2) A link *is not a form element*.  When you click a link you are just directing the user to a page, you're not posting a form.  For examples of how to use HTML forms to post data to PHP code you are encouraged to consult some introductory PHP tutorials.

Comment: the form is in the same page update.php

Comment: @AhmadBilal: Once again, the code you're referring to is *not in the question*.  How can anybody help you if you are expecting us to simply assume that your code works and that you don't have to show it to us?  If you want help then you're going to have to provide a minimal and complete example of the problem, including debugging information.  ("It doesn't work" is not debugging information.)  To learn more about asking questions you are encouraged to start here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

> the query runs successfully

No it doesn't.  (And making assumptions like that is probably what's leading to your confusion.)  None of your PHP code is running because it's all inside this`if` condition:

```
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
```

And that condition is always false when you reach that page by clicking this (or any) link:

```
<a href="update.php?call=123" class="btn btn-light">update</a>
```

Given that you're also looking for other `$_POST` and `$_FILES` array values, clicking a link won't work for this at all.  What you're looking for is a form.  Something like this:

```
<form action="update.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="call" value="<?php echo $fetch1['pro_id']; ?>" />
    <input type="file" name="image1" />
    <input type="submit" name="reg_user" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Selecting a file and clicking the submit button would submit the form and include the values your server-side code is looking for.  Note also that you'll need to change `$_GET['call']` to `$_POST['call']` to get the "call" value from the POST array when submitting the form.